# Creating an app with flutter and sqflite does not open on another device

Tags: flutter, sqlite, flutter-windows

After desktop build application with flutter and sqflite the app run on my device but if i share it on other device the app not open
[the app on my pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P00v6.png)[the app on my pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WS2wG.png)

Only use flutter and  sqflite_common_ffi  to save and retrieve data

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some necessary DLL in the folder, I fear. At least you need flutter_windows.dll, msvcp140.dll, vcruntime140.dll and vcruntime140_1.dll.
See [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/windows/building#building-your-own-zip-file-for-windows)

Also, if you're using sql_common_ffi, you need sqlite3.dll.
See [here](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite_common_ffi)

Comment: but its work on my pc like this

Comment: @abderaoufmansouri Your pc is the one you developed the app on? If that's the case, maybe you already have the DLLs registered into Windows on some other path, so the OS knows where to find them and is capable of running the app without having them in the same folder as the EXE

Comment: Thanks, it worked on two different devices